# update previous year values with current year value in an access table field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sales reps table in my access 2016 database which has sales_rep_num (around 100 numbers)column, year column(years from 2009 to 2016) and a commission_pct vary from values between 0% to 100%. I need to create a separate column in which all the previous year values will be replaced by commission_pct of 2016. for an example from 2009 to 2015 different percentage values will be replaced by a one value of 2016. I need this for an marginal calculation. If anybody can help me with this it will be a great help.

Comment: Are you using ms-access or mysql?? It´s not the same and you should tag correctly your questions

Comment: I am using access 2016

Comment: You really want to change data? Are these percentages associated with other records? If you change the historical percentages, how could you reproduce prior year information? What are rules for replacing values? If you went record-by-record to manually replace values, what would be the decision process?

Comment: That's why I want those in a separate column in that table. I need to update that just for a marginal calculation. I have already back up the original data. So this won't effect the original numbers.

Comment: Okay, what are the rules? As an example: if the record is for 2009 use 0.10, if record is for 2010 use 0.15, etc. Really don't need to save to table. The value can be calculated in query. Or build a table that has the translations and join it to the data table in query.

Comment: @June7 is right. Use a query for this. Can't tell how without the rules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to look through the table and update all data in the new column (new_commission_pct) to the commission_pct of 2016. If my understanding is correct, I think you can create a UPDATE query to do this, or use vba.

Comment: can you please show me how to use any of those to get this done.

Comment: Please see if this works.     UPDATE table1 SET table1.commission_pct2 = DLookUp("commission_pct","table1","sales_year=2016") WHERE [table1].[sales_year]<2016

Comment: You can test this by creating a query, select the SQL view and paste the code there. You need to change the table name and field name accordingly.

Comment: sorry for the late reply as I was away for a bit. In my case there are several sales guys and they have several percentages. and 2016 percentages are different to each and every sales guy. so when I do this query it does not update separately. please advise.

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple columns (fields) for percentage? Like commission_pct1, commission_pct2, commission_pct3, etc? And they will be all replaced by commission_pct of 2016?